# Sort query using Pageable with fields that is not in Select clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So i have this code in my repository (Example):

```
@Query("SELECT distinct s FROM Model1 ss LEFT JOIN ss.model2 s "
Page<Model2> methodName(long customerId, Pageable pageable);
```

In **Model1** i have a field  **LocalDate lastDate**.
The code is executing ok if i am sorting by fields from **Model2** (by using Pageable)
but if i need to sort by model1 fields (for example by **lastDate**) i am getting error "could not resolve property". If i am adding this field in "Select" i am also getting error "cannot be cast to class Model2". What can i do for it? I dont want to add "Order by" clause and also i dont want to add this field "lastDate" to Model1 just. Is there other ways to solve this problem?

P.S
The pageable object is specified using the following method signature:

```
public PageRequest(int page, int size, Direction direction, String... properties)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

You are returning `Model2`, which has no Information about `lastDate`, so how would `JPA` know?

You can not add it to you `SELECT` statement either because the return Entity is of type `Model2` which again does not understand `lastDate`.

Your Model2 needs to understand `lastDate` in order to be able to sort/page by it.

In JPA, in order to be able to sort by a specific field, this field must be part of the returned entity in the select statement. You can't sort with a property that is not returned